# Why XMPP function returns nothing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xmpp, xmppframework

I found in the documentation this:

```
<iq type='get' id='2'>
    <query xmlns='jabber:iq:roster'/>
</iq>
```

And write it in Swift as:

```
public class func getGroups() {
    var xmppStream: XMPPStream?

    let iq: DDXMLElement = DDXMLElement.elementWithName("iq") as! DDXMLElement
    iq.addAttributeWithName("type", stringValue: "get")
    iq.addAttributeWithName("id", stringValue: "2")

    let query: DDXMLElement = DDXMLElement(name: "query", xmlns: "jabber:iq:roster") as! DDXMLElement
    iq.addChild(query)

    xmppStream?.sendElement(iq)
}
```

And when I run it from my ViewController as:

```
override func viewDidLoad(animated: Bool) {
    print("Group list: \(getGroups())")
}
```

it returns me empty value, just `Group list:`.

My question is, how can I run my function properly and get the result, because when I run my XMPP `<iq>` snippet in my server, it returns me value.

**UPDATE**
You can write or correct my code even in Objective C

**UPDATE**

```
extension OneRoster: XMPPStreamDelegate {
    public func xmppStream(sender: XMPPStream, didReceiveIQ ip: XMPPIQ) -> Bool {
        return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to reinvent `XMPPRoster` module bundled with `XMPPFramework`: just instantiate it and `activate` on your XMPPStream instance and it will automatically sync your roster and groups. `iPhoneXMPP` example show you roster with groups backed up by this module.

Comment: I think I do not need in it. Because I wrote code inside of OneRoster file, and it's already activated

Comment: If it is already activated you does not need to query roster again - take a look at XMPPRosterStorage instance which is already filled with your contacts and groups

Comment: I want to get groups(XEP 0083) and there are no such method to get this list

Comment: It's what I get when call `user.groups`: `[<XMPPGroupCoreDataStorageObject: 0x7f9e33829510> (entity: XMPPGroupCoreDataStorageObject; id: 0xd00000000004000a <x-coredata://4C5F01F2-A5AF-42B8-A1CC-004E2940D869/XMPPGroupCoreDataStorageObject/p1> ; data: <fault>)]`

Comment: It is expected, try to enumerate this array and print group names and you will see data

Comment: `user.groups.enumerate()` did you mean this? It returns the same `EnumerateSequence<Set<NSObject>>(base: Set([<XMPPGroupCoreDataStorageObject: 0x7fd2c280d4a0> (entity: XMPPGroupCoreDataStorageObject; id: 0xd00000000004000a <x-coredata://6C91F120-F567-4C61-9F3D-D4603FC1FC71/XMPPGroupCoreDataStorageObject/p1> ; data: <fault>)]))`

Comment: I mean you need to access exact values - `for name in user.groups.enumerate() {
    print("Group: \(name)")
}` - coredata objects are lazy and will not fetch data until it is required.

Comment: yes, I know it, but it returns this `Group: (0, <XMPPGroupCoreDataStorageObject: 0x7fe610d6b930> (entity: XMPPGroupCoreDataStorageObject; id: 0xd00000000004000a <x-coredata://0E5A4D06-658B-4810-97BB-B1BD5AB5C9CD/XMPPGroupCoreDataStorageObject/p1> ; data: <fault>))` . But it rights, I have just one group. It just cannot show it as a plain text =/

Comment: `for group in user.groups.enumerate() { print("Group: \(group.name)") }` - you can check XMPPGroupCoreDataStorageObject fields in source

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93977/discussion-between-orkhan-alizade-and-vitalyster).

Comment: Hi. Can I ask you one question?

Answer (score 1):

```
xmppStream?.sendElement(iq)
```

is like a request you make to server, so it wont be instant. 
You need to wait for delegate like 'didReceiveIQ:' to be called and there you will get response.

Dig this delegate and I am sure you will be able to get data as expected.

Comment: Thanks! I've updated my question. I have such function in my file already

Comment: It's what I get when call `user.groups`: `[<XMPPGroupCoreDataStorageObject: 0x7f9e33829510> (entity: XMPPGroupCoreDataStorageObject; id: 0xd00000000004000a <x-coredata://4C5F01F2-A5AF-42B8-A1CC-004E2940D869/XMPPGroupCoreDataStorageObject/p1> ; data: <fault>)]`

Comment: This is from core data and not response of IQ, let me know what IQ response you get in delegate method ?